# Strugling with updating a cassandra row in FluentCassandra

Tags: nosql, c#, cassandra

I have this problem with using Fluent Cassandra in a test application. All I want to do is set the `IsOnline` field to true inside the `SignIn` method, but I keep getting the exception `supercolumn parameter is not optional for super CF`.  I've tried many things, but haven't been able to get it to work.  All the data is created and inserted into my Cassandra Keyspace, but to change it again to `IsOnline` after insertion is failing me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using FluentCassandra;
using FluentCassandra.Connections;
using FluentCassandra.Types;
using FluentCassandra.Operations;
using FluentCassandra.ObjectSerializer;
using FluentCassandra.Linq;

namespace CassandraTryTwo
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void CreateDatabase()
        {
            using (var context = new CassandraContext(keyspace: "RadiumNet", host: "localhost"))
            {
                if (context.KeyspaceExists("RadiumNet"))
                {
                    context.DropKeyspace("RadiumNet");
                }

                var keyspace = new CassandraKeyspace("RadiumNet", context);

                keyspace.TryCreateSelf();
                keyspace.TryCreateColumnFamily(
                    new CassandraColumnFamilySchema
                    {
                        FamilyName = "Accounts",
                        FamilyType = ColumnType.Super,
                        KeyValueType = CassandraType.UTF8Type,
                        SuperColumnNameType = CassandraType.UTF8Type,
                        ColumnNameType = CassandraType.UTF8Type,
                        DefaultColumnValueType = CassandraType.UTF8Type
                    }
                );
            }

            return;
        }

        private static void SignUp(String email, String password, String name, String surname, String age)
        {
            using (var context = new CassandraContext(keyspace: "RadiumNet", host: "localhost"))
            {
                var accountFamily = context.GetSuperColumnFamily("Accounts");
                var accountColumn = accountFamily.Get(email).First();

                if (accountColumn.Count() > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User {0} already registered", email);
                }
                else
                {
                    dynamic account = accountColumn;

                    account = accountFamily.CreateRecord(key: email);

                    dynamic details = account.CreateSuperColumn();
                    details.Password = password;
                    details.Name = name;
                    details.Surname = surname;
                    details.Age = age;

                    dynamic flags = account.CreateSuperColumn();
                    flags.IsBlocked = "False";
                    flags.IsBanned = "False";
                    flags.IsOnline = "False";

                    account.Details = details;
                    account.Flags = flags;

                    context.Attach(account);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return;
        }

        private static void SignIn(String email, String password)
        {
            using (var context = new CassandraContext(keyspace: "RadiumNet", host: "localhost"))
            {
                var accountFamily = context.GetSuperColumnFamily("Accounts");
                var accountColumn = accountFamily.Get(email).First();

                if (accountColumn.Count() == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User {0} did not register", email);
                }
                else
                {
                    dynamic account = accountColumn;
                    dynamic details = account.Details;
                    dynamic flags = account.Flags;

                    if (details.Password != password)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("User {0} provided an invalid password", email);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        flags.IsOnline = "True";

                        Console.WriteLine("Welcome {0} {1}", details.Name, details.Surname);

                        context.Attach(account);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }

            return;
        }

        private static void SetupConsole()
        {
            Console.Title = "Cassandra Test";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

            Console.SetWindowSize(120, 40);
            Console.Clear();
        }

        private static void Pause()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetupConsole();

            CreateDatabase();

            SignUp("foo@bar.com", "BooBab", "Wynand", "Pieterse", "22");
            SignUp("gee@wiz.com", "GreenBab", "Henk", "Pieterse", "27");

            SignIn("foo@bar.com", "BooBab");
            SignIn("bla@gmail.com", "Grrr");
            SignIn("gee@wiz.com", "Breezer");

            Pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the Accounts CF defined as a SuperCF?  And which line (exactly) is the exception being thrown on?

Comment: Yes accounts is a SuperCF, and the error happens at the place where I call context.SaveChanges() function. I've tried the Attach function on top of the SaveChanges function, but it did not help, I also tried disconnecting the entity and reattaching it, but also, the same error keeps on happening